# Draw with TikZ a Pythagorean triangle with the squares of its sides and labels

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've made this checking the old questions and the TikZ manual and I want to draw the squares of the sides of my Pythagorean triangle.

So far I have

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]%,cap=round,>=latex]

\coordinate [label=left:$C$] (A) at (-1.5cm,-1.cm);
\coordinate [label=right:$A$] (C) at (1.5cm,-1.0cm);
\coordinate [label=above:$B$] (B) at (1.5cm,1.0cm);
\draw (A) -- node[above] {$a$} (B) -- node[right] {$c$} (C) -- node[below] {$b$} (A);

\draw (1.25cm,-1.0cm) rectangle (1.5cm,-0.75cm);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image: output]

Comment: Can you explain better what you mean by squares on the sides? Maybe make a sketch such that we can see what you talking about.

Comment: Also see [this animated version](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159017/5764)...

Comment: You sure you want squares? ;) http://math.stackexchange.com/a/676075/30160

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First things first: let's make the width and height of the triangle into constants, so that we can change them later if we need to. These are the values that you used, but by loading them once and computing everything else on the fly, it makes it easier to change things around later:

```
\newcommand{\pythagwidth}{3cm}
\newcommand{\pythagheight}{2cm}
```

Next, relabel your coordinates so that the name matches the label which gets printed, otherwise we'll get horribly confused.

```
\coordinate [label={below right:$A$}] (A) at (0, 0);
\coordinate [label={above right:$B$}] (B) at (0, \pythagheight);
\coordinate [label={below left:$C$}] (C) at (-\pythagwidth, 0);
```

Two of the rectangles (the ones matching the horizontal and vertical edges) are easy to draw, if a little verbose:

```
\draw [dashed] (A) -- node [below] {$b$} ++ (-\pythagwidth, 0)
                -- node [right] {$b$} ++ (0, -\pythagwidth)
                -- node [above] {$b$} ++ (\pythagwidth, 0)
                -- node [left] {$b$} ++ (0, \pythagwidth);

\draw [dashed] (A) -- node [right] {$c$} ++ (0, \pythagheight)
                -- node [below] {$c$} ++ (\pythagheight, 0)
                -- node [left] {$c$} ++ (0, -\pythagheight)
                -- node [above] {$c$} ++ (-\pythagheight, 0);
```

These changes get us most of the way:

[image]

and then we need to draw the square corresponding to the hypotenuse. Computing the hypotenuse itself seems excessive (read: I’m tired and can’t remember how to do it now `:P`). Instead, we can use a little plane geometry:

[image]

We can find another edge of the square by rotating the original triangle through 90 degrees, and then translating appropriately. We can use the same method to find the two extra coordinates of the hypotenuse square in TikZ:

```
\coordinate (D1) at (-\pythagheight, \pythagheight + \pythagwidth);
\coordinate (D2) at (-\pythagheight - \pythagwidth, \pythagwidth);
```

and then drawing this square is simple:

```
\draw [dashed] (C) -- node [above left] {$a$} (B)
                   -- node [below left] {$a$} (D1)
                   -- node [below right] {$a$} (D2)
                   -- node [above right] {$a$} (C);
```

So putting this all together, we have:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\pythagwidth}{3cm}
\newcommand{\pythagheight}{2cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \coordinate [label={below right:$A$}] (A) at (0, 0);
  \coordinate [label={above right:$B$}] (B) at (0, \pythagheight);
  \coordinate [label={below left:$C$}] (C) at (-\pythagwidth, 0);

  \coordinate (D1) at (-\pythagheight, \pythagheight + \pythagwidth);
  \coordinate (D2) at (-\pythagheight - \pythagwidth, \pythagwidth);

  \draw [very thick] (A) -- (C) -- (B) -- (A);

  \newcommand{\ranglesize}{0.3cm}
  \draw (A) -- ++ (0, \ranglesize) -- ++ (-\ranglesize, 0) -- ++ (0, -\ranglesize);

  \draw [dashed] (A) -- node [below] {$b$} ++ (-\pythagwidth, 0)
            -- node [right] {$b$} ++ (0, -\pythagwidth)
            -- node [above] {$b$} ++ (\pythagwidth, 0)
            -- node [left] {$b$} ++ (0, \pythagwidth);

  \draw [dashed] (A) -- node [right] {$c$} ++ (0, \pythagheight)
            -- node [below] {$c$} ++ (\pythagheight, 0)
            -- node [left] {$c$} ++ (0, -\pythagheight)
            -- node [above] {$c$} ++ (-\pythagheight, 0);

  \draw [dashed] (C) -- node [above left] {$a$} (B)
                     -- node [below left] {$a$} (D1)
                     -- node [below right] {$a$} (D2)
                     -- node [above right] {$a$} (C);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Comment: If you zoom in the point `A` you'll see that lines are not nicely typeset; if you use instead `\draw [very thick] (A) -- (C) -- (B) -- cycle;` the lines will be perfectly molded together. Nice answer, BTW `:)`

Comment: I'd also use a round cap for the joints to have a better view near the vertex.

Answer (score 20):

A more simplified version than the original one; the idea here is simply to use

```
($ (<name1>) ! {sin(90)} ! 90:(<name2>) $)
```

to find a point in the perpendicular from `<name1>` to the line segment joining `<name1>` and `<name2>`; the distacence between the new point and `<name1>` is the same as the one between `<name1>` and `<name2>`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]
\coordinate [label=left:$A$] (A) at (-1.5cm,-1.cm);
\coordinate [label=below right:$C$] (C) at (1.5cm,-1.0cm);
\coordinate [label=above:$B$] (B) at (1.5cm,1.0cm);

\draw 
  (A) -- 
  node[above] {$c$} (B) -- 
  node[right] {$b$} (C) -- 
  node[below] {$a$} 
  (A);
\draw 
  (1.25cm,-1.0cm) rectangle (1.5cm,-0.75cm);

\coordinate (aux1) at
  ($ (A) ! {sin(90)} ! 90:(B) $);
\coordinate (aux2) at
  ($ (aux1) ! {sin(90)} ! 90:(A) $);

\coordinate (aux3) at
  ($ (A) ! {sin(90)} ! -90:(C) $);
\coordinate (aux4) at
  ($ (aux3) ! {sin(90)} ! -90:(A) $);

\coordinate (aux5) at
  ($ (C) ! {sin(90)} ! -90:(B) $);
\coordinate (aux6) at
  ($ (aux5) ! {sin(90)} ! -90:(C) $);

\draw[ultra thick,green,text=black]
  (A) -- 
  (aux1) node[midway,auto,swap] {$c$} -- 
  (aux2) node[midway,auto,swap] {$c$} -- 
  (B) node[midway,auto,swap] {$c$};
\draw[ultra thick,green,text=black]
  (A) -- 
  (aux3) node[midway,auto] {$a$} -- 
  (aux4) node[midway,auto] {$a$}  -- 
  (C) node[midway,auto] {$a$};
\draw[ultra thick,green,text=black]
  (C) -- 
  (aux5) node[midway,auto] {$b$} -- 
  (aux6) node[midway,auto] {$b$} -- 
  (B) node[midway,auto] {$b$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This allows the definition of a command for the construction of the squares in the general case (for any three non-colinear points):

```
\PythTr[<options>]{<name1>}{<name2>}{<name3>}{<coord1>}{<coord2>}{<coord3>}
```

where `<name1>`,...,`<name3>` are the names for the vertices and `<coor1>`,...,`<coor3>` are the coordinates for the three vertices; the optional argument can be used to pass options to control how the squares are drawn. For example, the figure below was obtained symply with

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\PythTr{A}{B}{C}{(-1.5cm,-1.cm)}{(1.5cm,-1.0cm)}{(1.5cm,1.0cm)}
\end{tikzpicture}\par\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
\PythTr[Maroon,dashed]{L}{M}{N}{(2,-2)}{(4,2)}{(0,2)}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand\PythTr[7][ultra thick,green,text=black]{%
\coordinate [label=left:$#2$] (#2) at #5;
\coordinate [label=below right:$#4$] (#4) at #6;
\coordinate [label=above:$#3$] (#3) at #7;

\draw 
  (#2) -- 
  node[auto] {$\MakeLowercase{#4}$} (#3) -- 
  node[auto] {$\MakeLowercase{#3}$} (#4) -- 
  node[auto] {$\MakeLowercase{#2}$} 
  (#2);

\coordinate (aux1) at
  ($ (#2) ! {sin(90)} ! 90:(#3) $);
\coordinate (aux2) at
  ($ (aux1) ! {sin(90)} ! 90:(#2) $);

\coordinate (aux3) at
  ($ (#2) ! {sin(90)} ! -90:(#4) $);
\coordinate (aux4) at
  ($ (aux3) ! {sin(90)} ! -90:(#2) $);

\coordinate (aux5) at
  ($ (#4) ! {sin(90)} ! -90:(#3) $);
\coordinate (aux6) at
  ($ (aux5) ! {sin(90)} ! -90:(#4) $);

\begin{scope}[#1]
\draw
  (#2) -- 
  (aux1) node[midway,auto,swap] {$\MakeLowercase{#4}$} -- 
  (aux2) node[midway,auto,swap] {$\MakeLowercase{#4}$} -- 
  (#3) node[midway,auto,swap] {$\MakeLowercase{#4}$};
\draw
  (#2) -- 
  (aux3) node[midway,auto] {$\MakeLowercase{#2}$} -- 
  (aux4) node[midway,auto] {$\MakeLowercase{#2}$}  -- 
  (#4) node[midway,auto] {$\MakeLowercase{#2}$};
\draw
  (#4) -- 
  (aux5) node[midway,auto] {$\MakeLowercase{#3}$} -- 
  (aux6) node[midway,auto] {$\MakeLowercase{#3}$} -- 
  (#3) node[midway,auto] {$\MakeLowercase{#3}$};
\end{scope}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\PythTr{A}{B}{C}{(-1.5cm,-1.cm)}{(1.5cm,-1.0cm)}{(1.5cm,1.0cm)}
\end{tikzpicture}\par\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
\PythTr[Maroon,dashed]{L}{M}{N}{(2,-2)}{(4,2)}{(0,2)}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In case the construction has to be restricted to just rectangle triangles, here's the corresponding version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand\PythTri[7][ultra thick,green,text=black]{%
\coordinate [label=left:$#2$] (#2) at #5;
\coordinate [label=below right:$#4$] (#4) at #6;
\coordinate (aux) at ($ #5 ! 1 ! 90:#6 $);
\coordinate [label=above:$#3$] (#3) at ($ #5 !#7!(aux) $);

\draw 
  (#2) -- 
  node[auto] {$\MakeLowercase{#4}$} (#3) -- 
  node[auto] {$\MakeLowercase{#3}$} (#4) -- 
  node[auto] {$\MakeLowercase{#2}$} 
  (#2);

\coordinate (aux1) at
  ($ (#2) ! {sin(90)} ! 90:(#3) $);
\coordinate (aux2) at
  ($ (aux1) ! {sin(90)} ! 90:(#2) $);

\coordinate (aux3) at
  ($ (#2) ! {sin(90)} ! -90:(#4) $);
\coordinate (aux4) at
  ($ (aux3) ! {sin(90)} ! -90:(#2) $);

\coordinate (aux5) at
  ($ (#4) ! {sin(90)} ! -90:(#3) $);
\coordinate (aux6) at
  ($ (aux5) ! {sin(90)} ! -90:(#4) $);

\begin{scope}[#1]
\draw
  (#2) -- 
  (aux1) node[midway,auto,swap] {$\MakeLowercase{#4}$} -- 
  (aux2) node[midway,auto,swap] {$\MakeLowercase{#4}$} -- 
  (#3) node[midway,auto,swap] {$\MakeLowercase{#4}$};
\draw
  (#2) -- 
  (aux3) node[midway,auto] {$\MakeLowercase{#2}$} -- 
  (aux4) node[midway,auto] {$\MakeLowercase{#2}$}  -- 
  (#4) node[midway,auto] {$\MakeLowercase{#2}$};
\draw
  (#4) -- 
  (aux5) node[midway,auto] {$\MakeLowercase{#3}$} -- 
  (aux6) node[midway,auto] {$\MakeLowercase{#3}$} -- 
  (#3) node[midway,auto] {$\MakeLowercase{#3}$};
\end{scope}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
\PythTri{A}{B}{C}{(0,4)}{(2,0)}{3cm}
\end{tikzpicture}\par\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
\PythTri[Maroon,dashed]{L}{M}{N}{(0,0)}{(4,0)}{3cm}
\end{tikzpicture}\par\bigskip

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now the command has the syntax

```
\PythTri[<options>]{<name1>}{<name2>}{<name3>}{<coord1>}{<coord2>}{<length>}
```

where `<coord1>` and `<coord2>` are the coordinates for one of the cathetus and the sixth mandatory argument is used now for the length of the other cathetus.

### Initial version:

One option using the `calc` library:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]
  \coordinate [label=left:$C$] (A) at (-1.5cm,-1.cm);
  \coordinate [label=right:$A$] (C) at (1.5cm,-1.0cm);
  \coordinate [label=above:$B$] (B) at (1.5cm,1.0cm);

\draw 
  (A) -- 
  node[above] {$a$} (B) -- 
  node[right] {$c$} (C) -- 
  node[below] {$b$} 
  (A);
\draw 
  (1.25cm,-1.0cm) rectangle (1.5cm,-0.75cm);
\draw[ultra thick,green] 
  let \p1= ( $ (C)-(A) $ )
  in (A) -- 
  ++(-90:{veclen(\x1,\y1)}) --       
  ++(0:{veclen(\x1,\y1)}) --       
  ++(90:{veclen(\x1,\y1)});     
\draw[ultra thick,green] 
  let \p1= ( $ (B)-(C) $ )
  in (B) -- 
  ++(0:{veclen(\x1,\y1)}) --       
  ++(-90:{veclen(\x1,\y1)}) --       
  ++(180:{veclen(\x1,\y1)});     
\coordinate (aux1) at
  ($ (A) ! {sin(90)} ! 90:(B) $);
\coordinate (aux2) at
  ($ (aux1) ! {sin(90)} ! 90:(A) $);
\draw[ultra thick,green]
  (A) -- (aux1) -- (aux2) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ¡Gracias Gonzalo! Estaba pidiendo algo como lo que publicaste. Me ha sido de mucha ayuda.

Comment: @user48419 ¡De nada! Me alegro que haya sido de ayuda.

Comment: @user48419 By the way, I updated my answer providing a simple macro to draw the whole construct. It might be of interest for you.

Comment: How can I add square grid to each of the thee squares to illustrate that $3^2+4^2=5^2$?

Answer (score 12):

Here's another option using the beautiful [`tkz-euclide`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-euclide) package (the code is a variation of an example from the documentation):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){C}
\tkzDefPoint(4,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(0,3){B}
\tkzDefSquare(B,A)\tkzGetPoints{E}{F}
\tkzDefSquare(A,C)\tkzGetPoints{G}{H}
\tkzDefSquare(C,B)\tkzGetPoints{I}{J}
\tkzFillPolygon[fill = red!50 ](A,C,G,H)
\tkzFillPolygon[fill = blue!50 ](C,B,I,J)
\tkzFillPolygon[fill = green!50](B,A,E,F)
\tkzFillPolygon[fill = orange,opacity=.5](A,B,C)
\tkzDrawPolygon[line width = 1pt](A,B,C)
\tkzDrawPolygon[line width = 1pt](A,C,G,H)
\tkzDrawPolygon[line width = 1pt](C,B,I,J)
\tkzDrawPolygon[line width = 1pt](B,A,E,F)
\tkzLabelSegment[auto](A,C){$a$}
\tkzLabelSegment[auto](C,G){$a$}
\tkzLabelSegment[auto](G,H){$a$}
\tkzLabelSegment[auto](H,A){$a$}
\tkzLabelSegment[auto](C,B){$b$}
\tkzLabelSegment[auto](B,I){$b$}
\tkzLabelSegment[auto](I,J){$b$}
\tkzLabelSegment[auto](J,C){$b$}
\tkzLabelSegment[auto](B,A){$c$}
\tkzLabelSegment[auto](F,B){$c$}
\tkzLabelSegment[auto](E,F){$c$}
\tkzLabelSegment[auto](A,E){$c$}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

A MetaPost version. Most of the drawing is done by two macros, `pythagorean_square` which draws a square based on a vertex, and `pythagorean_config` which draws the triange and calls `pythagorean_square` for each vertex.

These macros can be used for any kind of triangle. To ensure that it is a rectangle triangle is left to the user. The apices can be given as arguments of `pythagorean_config` in any order, clockwise or counterclockwise: by making use of the `turningnumber` function of MetaPost, it is ensured that the squares are always exterior to the triangle.

I give a LuaLaTeX version of my MetaPost code, which makes use of the `luamplib` package, but needs of course to be typeset by LuaLaTeX, and a second version which can be used with all LaTeX dialects, using the `gmp` package and thus requiring to be typeset with the `shell-escape` option activated if the user doesn't want to be bothered with more than one compilation.

```
% Luamplib version
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{luamplib}
  \mplibsetformat{metafun}
  \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
  \everymplib{verbatimtex \leavevmode etex; 
    % Right angle mark
    % From "Tutorial in MetaPost" by André Heck
    mark_size := 2mm;
    vardef mark_right_angle(expr endofa, common, endofb) =
      save tn; tn := turningnumber(common--endofa--endofb--cycle);
      draw ((1, 0)--(1,1)--(0,1))
      zscaled (mark_size * unitvector((1+tn)*endofa+(1-tn)*endofb-2*common))
        shifted (common*u) ;
    enddef;
    % Drawing of a Pythagorean square based on vertex [AB]
    vardef pythagorean_square(expr A, B, legend)(text drawing_options) =
      save D, E, v, my_square, my_center; 
      pair D, E, v, c, my_center; path my_square; clearxy; 
      z = B - A; 
      v = (-y, x);
      if t = 1:
        E = A - v;
        D = B - v;
      else:
        D = B + v;
        E = A + v;
      fi;
      my_square = B--D--E--A--cycle;
      my_center = center my_square;
      draw (B--D--E--A) scaled u drawing_options;
      freelabel(legend, u*0.5[A, E], u*(my_center reflectedabout (A, E)));
      freelabel(legend, u*0.5[E, D], u*(my_center reflectedabout (D, E)));
      freelabel(legend, u*0.5[D, B], u*(my_center reflectedabout (D, B)));
      freelabel(legend, u*0.5[A, B], u*(my_center reflectedabout (A, B)));
    enddef;
    % Drawing of the triangle and all its Pythagorean squares
    vardef pythagorean_config(expr A, B, C, c, a, b)(text drawing_options) =
      if angle(B-A) - angle(C-A) <> 0:
        t = turningnumber(A--B--C--cycle);
        pythagorean_square(A, B, c)(drawing_options);
        pythagorean_square(B, C, a)(drawing_options); 
        pythagorean_square(C, A, b)(drawing_options);
        draw (A--B--C--cycle) scaled u;
      fi;
    enddef;
    beginfig(0);}
  \everyendmplib{endfig;}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{mplibcode}
    u = 2.5cm;
    pair A, B, C; A = origin; B = (1, 0); C = (1,  1);
    label.llft("$A$", A*u); label.lrt("$B$", B*u); label.urt("$C$", C*u);
    pythagorean_config(A, B, C, "$c$", "$a$", "$b$")(dashed evenly);
    mark_right_angle(A, B, C);
  \end{mplibcode}
\end{center}

\bigskip
\begin{center}
  \begin{mplibcode}
    u := 1.75cm;
    pair A, B, C; A = origin; B = (0.5, 1.5); C = A + 1.5*(B-A) rotated -90;
    freelabel("$A$", A*u, u*0.5[B,C]); label.top("$B$", B*u); label.lrt("$C$", C*u);
    pythagorean_config(A, B, C, "$c$", "$a$", "$b$")(withcolor red);
    mark_right_angle(B, A, C);
  \end{mplibcode}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: Pythagorean squares]

```
% GMP version
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[latex, shellescape]{gmp}
\gmpoptions{everymp={%
  input latexmp; setupLaTeXMP(options="12pt", mode=rerun, textextlabel=enable); 
  % Right angle mark
  % From "Tutorial in MetaPost" by André Heck
  mark_size := 2mm;
  vardef mark_right_angle(expr endofa, common, endofb) =
    save tn; tn := turningnumber(common--endofa--endofb--cycle);
    draw ((1, 0)--(1,1)--(0,1))
      zscaled (mark_size * unitvector((1+tn)*endofa+(1-tn)*endofb-2*common))
    shifted (common*u) ;
  enddef;
  % Drawing of a Pythagorean square based on vertex [AB]
  vardef pythagorean_square(expr A, B, legend)(text drawing_options) =
    save D, E, v, my_square, my_center; pair D, E, v, c, my_center; path my_square; clearxy; 
    z = B - A; 
    v = (-y, x);
    if t = 1:
      E = A - v;
      D = B - v;
    else:
      D = B + v;
      E = A + v;
    fi;
    my_square = B--D--E--A--cycle;
    my_center = center my_square;
    draw (B--D--E--A) scaled u drawing_options;
    freelabel(legend, u*0.5[A, E], u*(my_center reflectedabout (A, E)));
    freelabel(legend, u*0.5[E, D], u*(my_center reflectedabout (D, E)));
    freelabel(legend, u*0.5[D, B], u*(my_center reflectedabout (D, B)));
    freelabel(legend, u*0.5[A, B], u*(my_center reflectedabout (A, B)));
  enddef;
  % Drawing of the triangle and all its Pythagorean squares
  vardef pythagorean_config(expr A, B, C, c, a, b)(text drawing_options) =
    if angle(B-A) - angle(C-A) <> 0:
      t := turningnumber(A--B--C--cycle);
      pythagorean_square(A, B, c)(drawing_options);
      pythagorean_square(B, C, a)(drawing_options); 
      pythagorean_square(C, A, b)(drawing_options);
      draw (A--B--C--cycle) scaled u;
    fi;
  enddef;}}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{mpost*}[mpmem = metafun]
    u := 2.5cm;
    pair A, B, C; A = origin; B = (1, 0); C = (1,  1);
    label.llft("$A$", A*u); label.lrt("$B$", B*u); label.urt("$C$", C*u);
    pythagorean_config(A, B, C, "$c$", "$a$", "$b$")(dashed evenly);
    mark_right_angle(A, B, C);
  \end{mpost*}
\end{center}

\bigskip
\begin{center}
  \begin{mpost*}[mpmem = metafun]
    u := 1.75cm;
    pair A, B, C; A = origin; B = (0.5, 1.5); C = A + 1.5*(B-A) rotated -90;
    freelabel("$A$", A*u, u*0.5[B,C]); label.top("$B$", B*u); label.lrt("$C$", C*u);
    pythagorean_config(A, B, C, "$c$", "$a$", "$b$")(withcolor red);
    mark_right_angle(B, A, C);
  \end{mpost*}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The labels don't match in either figure.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Fixed!

Answer (score 9):

A PSTricks solution where all you have to do is choose the lengths of the catheti (the values of `\lengthA` and `\lengthB`, respectively):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-eucl,pstricks-add}
\usepackage{xfp}

\newcommand*\maxHori{\fpeval{\lengthA+2*\lengthB}}
\newcommand*\maxVert{\fpeval{2*\lengthA+\lengthB}}

% labels
\def\Label[#1]#2#3{%
  \pcline[linestyle = none, offset = -8pt](#2)(#3)
  \ncput{$#1$}}

% lengths of the catheti
\def\lengthA{3 }
\def\lengthB{2 }


\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(\maxHori,\maxVert)
\psset{dimen = middel, fillstyle = solid}
  \pnodes%
    (\fpeval{\lengthA+\lengthB},\fpeval{\lengthA+\lengthB}){A}%
    (\lengthB,\lengthA){B}%
    (\fpeval{\lengthA+\lengthB},\lengthA){C}%
    (\lengthB,0){a1}%
    (\fpeval{\lengthA+\lengthB},0){a2}%
    (\fpeval{\lengthA+2*\lengthB},\fpeval{\lengthA+\lengthB}){b1}%
    (\fpeval{\lengthA+2*\lengthB},\lengthA){b2}%
    (0,\fpeval{2*\lengthA}){c1}%
    (\lengthA,\fpeval{2*\lengthA+\lengthB}){c2}
  \psframe[fillcolor = red!70](a1)(C)
  \psframe[fillcolor = blue!70](C)(b1)
  \pspolygon[fillcolor = yellow!70](B)(c1)(c2)(A)
  \pspolygon[fillcolor = green!70](A)(C)(B)
  \pstRightAngle[RightAngleSize = 0.3, fillstyle = solid, fillcolor = green!70]{A}{C}{B}
  \uput[60](A){$A$}
  \uput[210](B){$B$}
  \uput[315](C){$C$}
  \Label[a]{a1}{B}
  \Label[a]{B}{C}
  \Label[a]{C}{a2}
  \Label[a]{a2}{a1}
  \Label[b]{C}{A}
  \Label[b]{A}{b1}
  \Label[b]{b1}{b2}
  \Label[b]{b2}{C}
  \Label[c]{B}{c1}
  \Label[c]{c1}{c2}
  \Label[c]{c2}{A}
  \Label[c]{A}{B}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output2]

Answer (score 8):

Needs only the values for the catheti of the triangle:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,geometry}

\newpsstyle{aStyle}{linecolor=red,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red!30}
\newpsstyle{bStyle}{linecolor=green,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green!30}
\newpsstyle{cStyle}{linecolor=blue,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!30}
\makeatletter
\def\psRTriangle{\pst@object{psRTriangle}}
\def\psRTriangle@i(#1,#2){%
  \addbefore@par{dimen=middle}%
  \begin@SpecialObj
  \pspolygon(0,0)(#1,0)(#1,#2)
  \end@SpecialObj  
  \psframe[style=aStyle](!#1 dup neg)
  \psframe[style=bStyle,origin={#1,0}](#2,#2)
  \rput{!#2 #1 atan}(0,0){%
    \psframe[style=cStyle](!#1 #2 Pyth dup)
    \psarc(!#1 #2 Pyth dup){0.5}{180}{270}\psdot(!#1 #2 Pyth 0.2 sub dup)
    \uput[90](!#1 #2 Pyth 2 div 0){c}\uput[180](!#1 #2 Pyth dup 2 div){c}}
  \psarc(#1,0){0.5}{90}{180}\psdot(!#1 0.2 sub 0.2)
  \psarcn(#1,0){0.5}{90}{0}\psdot(!#1 0.2 add 0.2)
  \psarc(!#1 #2 add #2){0.5}{180}{270}\psdot(!#1 #2 add 0.2 sub #2 0.2 sub)
  \psarc(0,0){0.5}{!#2 #1 atan}{!#2 #1 atan 90 add}\psdot(!#2 #1 atan rotate 0.2 0.2)
  \psarcn(0,0){0.5}{0}{-90}\psdot(0.2,-0.2)
  \psarc(!#1 dup neg){0.5}{90}{180}\psdot(!#1 0.2 sub dup neg)
  \uput[200](0,0){A}\uput[45](#1,#2){B}\uput[-45](#1,0){C}
  \uput[0](!#1 #2 2 div){a} \uput[-90](!#1 #2 2 div add 0){a}
  \uput[-90](!#1 2 div 0){b}\uput[0](!0 #1 2 div neg){b}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-2,-5)(14,7)
\psRTriangle(3,2)
\newpsstyle{cStyle}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=magenta!20!black!20}
\rput(7,0){\psRTriangle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow](5,1.5)}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Just for typing warm-up exercise with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl,pst-plot}

\def\S#1#2#3{% #1: semi-width, #2: label, #3: fillcolor
\begin{pspicture}[plotpoints=5](-#1,-#1)(#1,#1)
    \curvepnodes{0}{360}{#1 2 sqrt mul t 45 add PtoC}{#2}
    \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=#3!50](#20)(#21)(#22)(#23)
    \psset{linestyle=none,offset=.1}
    \multido{\ix=0+1,\iy=1+1}{4}{\ncline{#2\ix}{#2\iy}\naput{$#2$}}
\end{pspicture}}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-5)(8,8)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={-135,-45,45},PointSymbol=none]{A}(4,0){C}(4,3){B}
    \pstRightAngle{A}{C}{B}
    \rput[tl](A){\S{2}{b}{red}}
    \rput[bl](C){\S{1.5}{a}{green}}
    \rput[br]{(B)}(B){\S{2.5}{c}{blue}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I'm surprised how long are all tikz answers (the only short answer is the PSTrick answer of stalking is prohibited). So I giving here a short one using `to path`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{square/.style= { to path={ let \p1=(\tikztostart), \p2=(\tikztotarget),
  \p3=($(\p2)!1!90:(\p1)$), \p4=($(\p1)!1!-90:(\p2)$) in
  (\p2) foreach \i in {3,4,1,2} {--node[auto=right]{#1} (\p\i)}}}}

\begin{document}
  \tikz[very thick] \draw (0,0) to[square=a] (0:3) to[square=b] ([turn]90:2) to[square=c] (0,0);
\end{document}
```

[image]