# Strange behaviour trying to draw a pythagorean triangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw a right triangle with sqares over its sides to illustrate Pythagoras' theorem. Here's my code

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
\coordinate[label=200:$A$]  (A) at (0,0) ;
\coordinate[label=120:$B$]  (B) at (0,1)  ;
\coordinate[label=right:$C$] (C) at (1,0) ;
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (A) ;
\draw (A) rectangle (0.08,0.08);
\draw[rotate=90] (A)    let
                        \p1=(B),
                        \p2=(A),
                        \n1={veclen(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)}
                    in
                        rectangle (\n1,\n1);
\draw[rotate=270] (A)   let
                        \p1=(C),
                        \p2=(A),
                        \n3={veclen(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)}
                    in
                        rectangle (\n3,\n3);
\draw[rotate=45] (C) let 
                        \p2=(B),
                        \p1=(C),
                        \n2={veclen(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)}
                    in
                        rectangle (\n2,\n2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

As far as I can see I'm doing nothing wrong. But the picture I get is the following:

[image: The hypothenuse rectangle is all wrong]

Now there are more elegant solutions to this problem, for instance [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166958/draw-with-tikz-a-pythagorean-triangle-with-the-squares-of-its-sides-and-labels); but I want to know why my code doesn't do what it is expected.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tray

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
\coordinate[label=200:$A$]  (A) at (0,0) ;
\coordinate[label=120:$B$]  (B) at (0,1)  ;
\coordinate[label=right:$C$] (C) at (1,0) ;
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle ;
\draw (A) rectangle (0.08,0.08);
\draw[red] (A)    let% <---
                        \p1=(B),
                        \p2=(A),
                        \n1={veclen(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)}
                    in
                        rectangle +(-\n1,\n1);% <---
\draw[blue] (A)   let% <---
                        \p1=(A),
                        \p2=(B),
                        \n2={veclen(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)}
                    in

                        rectangle +(\n2,-\n2);% <---
\draw[rotate=45] (C) let
                        \p2=(B),
                        \p1=(C),
                        \n3={veclen(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)}
                    in
                        rectangle + (\n3,\n3);% <---
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Differences to your MWE are designated by `% <---%. This code gives:

[image]

Note: angle for rotate third rectangle is `45 degrees˙only if the first and second are of the same size ...

**Addadendum:**
Your triangle have equal cathetus, so the `\n2` is not necessary to calculate. Shorter code is:

```
\draw   let \p1=(A),
            \p2=(B),
            \n1={veclen(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)} in
            (A) rectangle +(-\n1,\n1) 
            (A) rectangle +(\n1,-\n1);
```

Comment: Magic! Thank you... could you please refer me to the explanation? What does the '+' do?

Comment: + means relative coordinate. This in case of red rectangle it start at coordinate `(A)` and end in coordinate `((A) + (-\n1,\n1))`.

Comment: I added possible simplification in case of equal triangle cathetus.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you know how to get the coordinates for the edges of the square over the hypothenuse? I need to draw a line that ends there. Should I do that a separate question?

Comment: Two coordinates are know: `B` and `C`,. Other two edges can be calculated by `($(B)!\n3!90:(C)$)`  for coordinate perpendicular to coordinate `(C)` and `($(C)!\n3!90:(B)$)` (not tested, but should work). For details see *13.5.3 The Syntax of Partway Modifiers* in TikZ manual.