# Using \foreach to manage ticks in axis, Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to add minor distance between y ticks. The default distance is 0.5, I need to set for 0.2.
It seems easy to set different space for ticks according to **pgfplots**, in 4.15, page 271.

I add the suggested `ytick={\foreach \y in {.2,.4,.6}{\y}`, varying to get results, but I couldn't. Help me, please.

My code graph is, with `\usepackage{tikz}` and `\usepackage{pgfplots}`, in the preamble:

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\caption{Rigidez Efectiva para Columnas Rectangulares}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:.7]
\begin{axis}[xlabel={$P/A_{g}f'{c}$},ylabel={$EI_{ef}/EI_{g}$}, xmin=-.1,xmax=.7,ymin=0,ymax=1.4, ytick={\foreach \y in {.2,.4,.6}{\y}}]
\addplot[domain=-.1:.1,color=red,very thick]{.3};
\addplot[domain=.1:.5,color=red,very thick]{.2+\x};
\addplot[domain=.5:.7,color=red,very thick]{.7};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: `\foreach` is not needed in tick specification. Simply use `ytick={0.2,0.4,0.6}` and it works as expected.

Comment: It's right, it works, thanks. The pgfplots manual is complicated. But in which cases I must use `\foreach` command?

Comment: It works with dots also: `ytick={.2,.4,...,1.2}`

Comment: `\foreach` is used very rarely; the mention of `\foreach` in 4.15.1 of the manual is telling you how the ticks are created internally (details of `pgfplots` implementation). The examples in the bulleted list show typical usage and the behavior of dots.

Comment: @PaulGessler an answer?

Comment: Yes, I'm so confused, what does it mean: details of `pgfplots` implementation. What will the results be in the graph?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mention of `\foreach` in Section 4.15.1 of the [`pgfplots`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) manual (version 1.10) is just to explain how the tick list is processed internally; it has nothing to do with how the tick list should be written.

Take the examples in the bullet list immediately following as your guide for tick specification. I have included this list below, for reference:

> - `{0,1,2,5,8,1e1,1.5e1}` (a series of coordinates),
> - `{0,...,5}` (the same as `{0,1,2,3,4,5}`),
> - `{0,2,...,10}` (the same as `{0,2,4,6,8,10}`), and
> - `{9,...,3.5}` (the same as `{9,8,7,6,5,4}`).
> - See [Section 83 of the [PGF/TikZ](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) manual (version 3.0.0)] for a more detailed definition of the options.

In this particular case, `ytick={0.2,0.4,0.6}` does the job nicely:

### Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:.7]
\begin{axis}[
  xlabel={$P/A_{g}f'{c}$},
  ylabel={$EI_{ef}/EI_{g}$},
  xmin=-0.1, xmax=0.7,
  ymin=0.0, ymax=1.4, 
  ytick={0.2,0.4,0.6},
]
  \addplot[domain=-.1:.1,color=red,very thick]{.3};
  \addplot[domain=.1:.5,color=red,very thick]{.2+\x};
  \addplot[domain=.5:.7,color=red,very thick]{.7};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

A few notes: `pgfplots` loads `tikz` on its own, so a separate `\usepackage{}` is not necessary. Also, I added `pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}` (replace with your version if necessary)  to get better axis label spacing. Finally, I removed `domain=0:.7` from the `tikzpicture` options because it is overridden by each `\addplot` command anyway.

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks for improving the code. But I have a question about the suggestions of the manual. In which cases the inclusion of `\foreach` will be useful?

Comment: @Isai, the only times I use `\foreach` in an `axis` environment are for including plots of multiple functions/data files on a single axis. You can refer to my answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158817/21344) for a specific use case.