# How can I create airfoil images for fluid mechanics presentations in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need some help on how to create good looking vectorized images of these kinds of themes:

[image: example1]

[image: example2]
<sub>(source: [caltech.edu](http://authors.library.caltech.edu/25019/1/figs/fig305.gif))</sub>

I work a lot with Latex when it comes to typesetting so I have some basic experience with Tikz. However I feel that if I need to make complicated images like the ones above I find myself a bit lost.

I would very much appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction as to how i could go about making these kinds of images.

Comment: Hi Jack, welcome to the site! As it stands, this question isn't really a good fit for the site, since it doesn't revolve around a generalisable issue that could potentially be useful for someone else in the future. Even if someone needed to draw images that are very similar to these, they wouldn't be able to find the question (the question should, at the very least, include the word "airfoil", for instance). Ideally, though, you'd get started with drawing the images yourself and ask more specific questions as they come up.

Comment: Hi Jake, thanks for that point. I'll edit my question to include more specifics. In the meantime I am actually trying to draw what I posted, I just thought someone may have a quick solution. I will post my work as soon as I get somewhere!

Comment: Cross post of [Advice on how to make these types of images for PhD](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/34994/advice-on-how-to-make-these-types-of-images-for-phd) on graphicdesign.stackexchange.com.

Comment: It is not the answer to your question, but might motivate you if you have a look at [Nice scientific pictures show off](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158668/nice-scientific-pictures-show-off).

Comment: @Pouya Thats a great link, much appreciated!