# Drawing 3D picture

Tags: tikz-3dplot

How can I draw this shape?

Thanks

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to be a hyperboloid in perspective view, perhaps made with `asymptote`. I am not sure if it is easy to achieve this convincingly in `tikz-3dplot`, which uses an orthographic projection.

Comment: For instance, [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/285844/194703) seems to be good starting point. You only need to rotate it, change the color and the perspective.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a quick adaption of[Henri Menke's code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/285844/194703).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{asypictureB}

\begin{document}

\begin{asypicture}{name=hyperboloid}
settings.outformat="pdf";
settings.render = 16;
settings.prc = false;
import three;
import graph;

size(8cm,8cm);

currentprojection = perspective(3*(0.1,1,0), up=Y);

pen color = yellow;
material surfacepen = material(diffusepen=color+opacity(1.0), emissivepen=0.5*color);
pen color = blue;
material planepen = material(diffusepen=opacity(0.4), emissivepen=0.8*color);

real f(real x) { return .5*x*x+.5; }
path3 p3 = path3(graph(f, -1, 1, operator..));

surface solidsurface = surface(p3, c=O, axis=X);
draw(solidsurface, surfacepen=surfacepen);

draw(3Y-0.2Z -- 3Y+0.2Z,
L=Label("$x$",position=MidPoint),arrow=Arrow3(TeXHead3));

\end{asypicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The above can be compiled with `pdflatex -shell-escape`.

Alternatively, you can use

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
settings.outformat="pdf";
settings.render = 16;
settings.prc = false;
import three;
import graph;

size(8cm,8cm);

currentprojection = perspective(3*(0.1,1,0), up=Y);

pen color = yellow;
material surfacepen = material(diffusepen=color+opacity(1.0), emissivepen=0.5*color);
pen color = blue;
material planepen = material(diffusepen=opacity(0.4), emissivepen=0.8*color);

real f(real x) { return .5*x*x+.5; }
path3 p3 = path3(graph(f, -1, 1, operator..));

surface solidsurface = surface(p3, c=O, axis=X);
draw(solidsurface, surfacepen=surfacepen);

draw(3Y-0.2Z -- 3Y+0.2Z,
L=Label("$x$",position=MidPoint),arrow=Arrow3(TeXHead3));
\end{asy}
\end{document}
```

Assuming that this file is called `test.tex`, run

```
pdflatex test
asy test-1.asy
pdflatex test
```

In all the above you can replace `pdflatex` by `lualatex` or `xelatex`, this should also work.

If `asymptote` fails for some reason, here is a (comparatively poor, of course) `pgfplots` alternative.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}%<- change on older installations
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[hide axis,shader=interp,
    axis equal image,scale=2,view/el=4,view/az=0,
    colormap={pft}{rgb255(0cm)=(255,127,0);
    rgb255(1cm)=(255,255,0);rgb255(2cm)=(255,255,200)},
    point meta=-(y-1.5)*(y-1.5)*(1+x*x)/1.5-2*(z+2)*(z+2)-x*x,z buffer=sort]
 \addplot3[surf,domain=-2:2,
 domain y=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az}-180:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az}]
  ({sqrt(x*x+1)*cos(y)},{sqrt(x*x+1)*sin(y)},{(1-0.1*sin(y-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/view/az}))*x}); 
 \draw[semithick,-latex] (1.6,0,-0.7) -- (1.6,0,0.7) node[midway,right]{$X_0$}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: very very good. Thanks so much

Comment: Excuse me when I run this code it gives two errors: 1- File <Test-hyperboloid> not found.
2- I can not write on file <Test-compile_asy.bat>.
My input file name is `Test' and I'm using TeX Live 2019 updated to 2019-30-12

Comment: @BahmanMirzakhani One has to run with the `-shell-escape` option, e.g. `pdflatex -shell-escape`. You can also run `asy` on the asymptote code between `\begin{asypicture}{name=hyperboloid}` and `\end{asypicture}`.

Comment: I ran with `pdflatex -shell-escape` but give this error: `! Package asypictureB Error: Possible Asymptote error: SuspendThread failed`. Also I installed the asymptote program and ran those code you mentioned it produce the shape but I can not save it. What i should to do? Thanks

Comment: @BahmanMirzakhani I am sorry, I am not an expert on asymptote installation issues. I added an alternative way of compiling this, hoping that this one will work for you.

Comment: Thanks. I did it. The compile of LaTeX is correct but `asy test-1.asy` says: `SuspendThread failed`. What do you think could be the problem?

Comment: @BahmanMirzakhani I really don't know, sorry. (I added a poor pgfplots alternative, but I have no experience in debugging asymptote errors. You may ask a separate question on this.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Good job. Thanks so much