# How can I draw these three planes with tikz or pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw these planes in latex. The result should be very similar to the image. [image]

I'm a very beginner in tikz. Please help.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285835/tikz-planes-intersecting-hyperboloid?rq=1

Comment: Are these three particular planes (in which case can you give equations for them) or do you just need planes that look similar

Comment: @Willoughby Well I just need them to be similar :)