# Writing code for image

Tags: sourcecode

Can someone help me to write code for the following figure. I want to insert it in a presentation and am not well versed with graphics?

[image]

Comment: Do you mind learning TikZ or MetaPost? You will, eventually, if you do lots of drawings like this.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! What have you done so far? Tikz should do this job. Here is a nice example, which should help: [Nice scientific pictures show off](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158785/124842)

Comment: I am keen to learn Tikz or some other package. But I wanted it for a presentation. Secondly, I had no idea as to how should I start? \\ Anyway thanks for your advice

Comment: Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This produces something rather similar.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick] (0,0) -- (10,0) node[above,pos=0.4]{Ground plane};
\draw[latex-latex] (1,-1) -- (9,-1) node[midway,fill=white,minimum width=1cm] {$r$};
\coordinate (receiver) at (9,1);
\coordinate (fakereceiver) at (9,-1);
\coordinate (sender) at (1,3);
\coordinate (fakesender) at (1,-3);
%\coordinate (reflector) at (7,0);
\draw[thick] (sender) -- (receiver) node[above,pos=0.15]{\begin{tabular}{c}
sending\\ antenna\end{tabular}};
\coordinate (reflector) at (intersection of sender--fakereceiver and
fakesender--receiver); 
\draw[thick,-latex] (reflector) -- (receiver) node[above]{\begin{tabular}{c}
receive\\ antenna\end{tabular}};
\draw[thick,-latex] (sender) -- (reflector);
\draw[latex-latex] (0.5,0) -- (0.5,0 |- sender) node[midway,fill=white,minimum width=1cm]
{$h_s$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Any suggestions on how should I proceed in graphics

Comment: @Ehsa Please tell me more precisely what you mean, and give me a few minutes, I'm trying to improve the code...

Comment: Thanks for your concern. Actually, I want to learn Tikz or other relevant packages and want to know about some tutorials or simple examples to start with

Comment: @Ehsa I really enjoy learning Ti*k*Z, but I'd like to mention that the learning will never end ;-) I improved the above code in that I made sure that the signal gets really reflected, i.e. the impact angle and the angle of the outgoing signal match even if you move the sender and receiver around. (In this version, you need to adjust the fakesender and fakereceiver coordinates by hand, it can be automatized, but I think that would be too overwhelming for the moment.) Notice that this is a very nice forum and you will always get nice answers to appropriate questions, so learning will be fun.