# Electric field lines of a capacitor

Tags: pstricks, pst-electricfield

I’m unable to create the electric field lines of a capacitor shown in the uploaded picture. Could anyone give me please a hint? Thanks in advance.
[image: This is what i need :-)]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! 1) Could you post the code you've  got so far? 2) What do you mean exactly with ‘*paint* the electric field lines’? Adding colour to the lines? The same for everyline?

Comment: Have edit the main text and hope the question is now better to understand ... @Bernard: thx for your fast reply

Comment: The problem is we don't what model is used (and I'm not a physicist). The package allows to plot the electric fields for a finite number of charges.

Answer (score 2):

This is too long for a comment, and you asked for a nudge, not a solution, so I will post it as an answer.

Looking at the documentation for the package `pst-electricfield` I found the following example:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,pstricks]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pst-electricfield} 
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{pspicture*}(-10,-5)(6,5) 
        \psframe*[linecolor=lightgray!40](-10,-5)(6,5) 
        \psgrid[subgriddiv=0,gridcolor=lightgray,griddots=10] 
        \psElectricfield[Q={[600 -60 0 false][-4 0 0] },N=50,points=500,runit=0.8] 
        \psEquipotential[Q={[600 -60 0 false][-4 0 0]},linecolor=blue,Vmax=100,Vmin=50,stepV 
        =2](-10,-5)(6,5) 
        \psframe*(-10,-5)(-9.5,5) 
        \rput(0,0){\textcolor{white}{\large$-$}} 
        \multido{\rA=4.75+-0.5}{20}{\rput(-9.75,\rA){\textcolor{white}{\large$+$}}} 
\end{pspicture*} 
\end{document}
```

I think that if you can figure out how to create negatively charged wall to the right, and draw a bigger area, you are pretty much done.

That being said, I do not know a great deal about the package (I just find it very cool every time I look at [Nice scientific pictures show off](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158668/nice-scientific-pictures-show-off))

## Edit

The code yields:
[image]

## Edit 2

SO I had a go at creating a capacitor myself, and I think it turned out rather poorly, but here it is anyways:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-electricfield}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture*}(-7,-7)(7,7)
        \psframe*[linecolor=lightgray!40](-10,-5)(6,5)
        \psgrid[subgriddiv=0,gridcolor=lightgray,griddots=10]
        \psElectricfield[Q={
        [-6 -3 0 PtoC][6 3 0 30]
        [-6 -3 1 30][6 3 1 30]
        [-6 -3 2 30][6 3 2 30]
        [-6 -3 3 30][6 3 3 30]
        [-6 -3 -1 30][6 3 -1 30]
        [-6 -3 -2 30][6 3 -2 30]
        [-6 -3 -3 30][6 3 -3 30]
        [-6 -3 0.5 30][6 3 0.5 30]
        [-6 -3 -0.5 30][6 3 -0.5 30]
        [-6 -3 1.5 30][6 3 1.5 30]
        [-6 -3 2.5 30][6 3 2.5 30]
        [-6 -3 3.5 30][6 3 3.5 30]
        [-6 -3 -1.5 30][6 3 -1.5 30]
        [-6 -3 -2.5 30][6 3 -2.5 30]
        [-6 -3 -3.5 30][6 3 -3.5 30]
}
,N=50,points=500,runit=0.8]
\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

yields:

[image]

To create something closer to your wish I would need to know how to control the density of the  field lines and how to supress the drawing of the actual charges.