# Metapost error ! An expression can't begin with `]'

Tags: metapost

I am trying to reproduce the examples in Metapost showed [here](https://berndt-schwerdtfeger.de/wp-content/uploads/pdf/sphere.pdf) but I am having this error:

! An expression can't begin with `]'.
 
                0
 
                   ]
l.12 vector e[]
               ,u[];

This is the code:

```
prologues:=3;                % include all fonts
outputtemplate:="%j-%c.mps"; % output file will be file.mps
beginfig(1);
phi:=25;                     % latitude
lambda:=28;                  % longitude
Omega=35;                    % longitude of ascending node
incl=30;                     % inclination
omega=43;                    % longitude of periapsis in orbital plane
vector e[],u[];
e1=(1,0,0);                  % aries - vernal equinox
e2=(0,1,0);                  % e2=e x e1 - not used
e3=(0,0,1);                  % e3=e=ENP
endfig;
end.
```

Any ideas why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `vector` type in MetaPost, you have to use `pair` instead, and as its names suggests, there must be two coordinates, not three. MetaPost is a 2D-based language.

See the [featpost](https://ctan.org/pkg/featpost?lang=en) package for an example of MetaPost use for 3D drawings. See also the [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net) language, which is inspired by MetaPost and has full 3D abilities.

**Edit** Reading the linked article more thoroughly, I finally learnt that the author uses a `vector` type defined by Denis Roegel in this [TUGboat article](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0408/16bbe007e5b8d1d794458a446521505d5b34.pdf).

```
let vector=color;
  let Xp=redpart; let Yp=greenpart; let Zp=bluepart;
```

In fact, it's down to the same thing used in `featpost` (and the `tres` module provided by Metafun, see Henri Menke's comment below): using the `color` type for 3D-coordinates…

Comment: There is a three-pronged variant, but it’s for colors and is not suitable for coordinates.

Comment: @egreg As it happens, the `featpost` package I pointed in my answer uses the 3D color type for coordinates. :-) It seems to work, although I never tried it earnestly.

Comment: Naughty boys!!!

Comment: Metafun can do 3D as well using the [`tres` module](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/beta/metapost/context/base/mpiv/mp-tres.mpiv).  In ConTeXt you can use it via the [`three` module](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/beta/tex/context/modules/mkiv/m-three.mkiv) (this file also has examples).

Comment: @HenriMenke It reminds me somehow of the method I used for this peculiar drawing (method which was in turn inspired by the pst-3dplot package documentation): https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158746/25768 Anyway, it seems fairly limited compared to featpost, a fortiori compared to the extended 3D support provided by Asymptote.

Comment: @FranckPastor Is there any possible reason why he use vector type all over the document?

Comment: @Mac I've no idea… The best way to know it is probably to ask him directly. Maybe he uses some kind of self-made package I'm not aware of and which is not explicitly loaded in this document.

Comment: @Mac I've found it! He uses a kind of vector type defined in this paper of Denis Roegel: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0408/16bbe007e5b8d1d794458a446521505d5b34.pdf I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @FranckPastor I understand now! Thank you again