# Missing pst-calculate.sty (pst-optexp)

Tags: pstricks

I copied the code that yields the diagram presented [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158668/nice-scientific-pictures-show-off/158802#158802) but all I get is the error message

> ! LaTeX Error: File `pst-calculate.sty' not found. Type X to quit or
>    to proceed, or enter new name. (Default extension: sty) Enter
>   file name: ! Emergency stop.

I have just updated all my packages. When I look up the name of the missing style file, I find pst-calculate.tpm in the directory

> C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tpm\packages\pst-calculate.tpm

Also, the missing file can be found [here](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pst-calculate/latex/pst-calculate.sty). Will my problem be solved if I just save it to the correct folder? If so, which is it? Let me know if I need to give you more information.

EDIT:

Following UlrikeFischer's advice I managed to install the package pst-calculate, and after some tweaks, it worked. Thanks to Ulrike for the help.

Comment: It works fine for me. Did you check for updates as user *and* as admin?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I forgot to run miktex update as admin and ran it as simply user.  Weird thing is that now Windows can't find the miktex update program, which has got me worried thinking that it got deleted somehow. Any idea what I could do?

Comment: Search in the bin folder of miktex for miktex-console

Comment: @UlrikeFischer just ran it as admin and it found no updates. I still get the original error and the style file doesn't exist yet.

Comment: You can delete this question if you think this question is too  localized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Ulrike's suggestion, I installed the pst-calculate package from miktex-console and it solved the problem. Can't for the life of me explain what happened to Miktex Update, but my original problem was solved, so this question is closed.