# Graphic of Richardson Number

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, tikz-styles

I was inspired by the graphic **[Moon Synodic Period](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158668/nice-scientific-pictures-show-off/338201#338201)**, created by [Tangent Plane](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/118091/tangent-plane).
I insert the code here.
I tried to create scale definitions, so I could scale the graph and the text, but I'm not entirely satisfied with that.

Could I ask for suggestions to optimize the code? thanks

```
\documentclass[a4paper,portrate]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=0.3in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\makeatletter
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xpt}{\@xpt}{5}{4}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xipt}{\@xipt}{6}{5}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xiipt}{\@xiipt}{6}{5}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xivpt}{\@xivpt}{\@xpt}{6}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [
scale=0.5,
node font=\small,
dashed axis/.style={dash pattern=on 4pt off 2pt},
moon line/.style={dash pattern=on 8pt off 4pt},
information text/.style={rounded corners, fill=Info Color, inner sep=1ex}
]

\definecolor{Earth Color}{HTML}{358af3};
\definecolor{Sun Color}{HTML}{fffc00};
\definecolor{Moon Color}{HTML}{ddbd4c};
\definecolor{Info Color}{HTML}{eeeeee};

\def\ax{0}; %Posizione centrale assi%
\def\ay{0}
%%--Scale Factor --------------------
\def\sca{1}
\def\scaa{0.9}
% Asse x e y
\draw[{Stealth[length=0.01cm]}-{Stealth[length=0.2cm]}] (-16, 0) -- (16, 0) node [scale=\sca,right=0.1em] {$P_{G}$}; % Asse 
\draw[{Stealth[length=0.001cm]}-{Stealth[length=0.2cm]}] (0, -0) -- (0, 16) node [scale=\sca,above=0.1em] {$P_{M}$};

%%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\path (0, 0) node [scale=\sca,shift={(7,1)}] {CL};
\path (0, 0) node [scale=\sca,shift={(4.2,0.2)}] { $P_{G}>>P_{M}$};
\path (0, 0) node [scale=\sca,shift={(4.5, 4)}, anchor=north west] {CM};
\path (0, 0) node [scale=\sca,shift={(2.5, 3)}, anchor=north west] {$P_{M}\approx P_{G}$};
\path (0, 0) node [scale=\sca,shift={(0,7)},draw=black,fill=white] {CF};
\path (0, 0) node [scale=\sca,shift={(0,6)},draw=black,fill=white] {$P_{M}>>P_{G}$};
\path (0, 0) node [scale=\sca,shift={(0,5)},draw=black,fill=white] {$R_{i}=0$};
\path (0, 0) node [scale=\sca,shift={(-4.5, 4)}, anchor=north west] {TFS};
\path (0, 0) node [scale=\sca,shift={(-4.5, 3)}, anchor=north west] {$P_{M}>0,P_{G}<0$};
\path (0, 0) node [scale=\sca,shift={(-7,1)}] {FS};
\path (0, 0) node [scale=\sca,shift={(-4.2,0.2)}] { $P_{M}\approx 0,P_{G}<0$};
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\path (0, 0) node [scale=\sca,shift={(6.5,0)},draw=black,fill=white] {$R_{i}=+\infty$};
\path (0, 0) node [scale=\sca,shift={(-6.5,0)},draw=black,fill=white] {$R_{i}=+\infty$};
%
\begin{scope}[rotate around={-75:(0, 0)}]
\draw[{Stealth[length=0.01cm]}-{Stealth[length=0.01cm]}] (0, -0) -- (0, 15) node [scale=\sca,rotate = 45, above=-1em] {};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[rotate around={75:(0, 0)}]
\draw[-] (0, -0) -- (0, 15) node [ rotate = -15, right = 20,left=0.5em] {};
\end{scope}

\path (0, 0) node [scale=\sca,shift={(-3.7,1)}, draw=black,fill=white,rotate = -15] {$R_{i}\approx+1$};
\path (0, 0) node [scale=\sca,shift={(3.7,1)}, draw=black,fill=white,rotate = 15] {{ $ R_{i}\approx-1$}};

% draw line
\begin{scope}[rotate around={-20:(0, 0)}]
\draw[moon line] (0, 0) -- (0, 15);
\node [shift={(-0.8,1)}] at (0, 7) {};];
\end{scope}
% draw line
\begin{scope}[rotate around={20:(0, 0)}]
\draw[moon line] (0, 0) -- (0, 15);
\end{scope}


\foreach \i in {5,...,1}
{
    \pgfmathparse{(160/3.8)*(\i)-396};
    \node[scale=\sca] at (\pgfmathresult:5cm) {\i};
};

%draw information box
\draw[shift={(6, 10)}] node[scale=\scaa,above right, text width=4cm,information text] {
    \small
    {\boldmath
        \textbf{\underline{Indice}} }
    \vspace{1ex}
    \small
    \begin{description}
    {\boldmath
        \item[CL]: Libera;
        \item[CM]: Mista;
        \item[CF]: Forzata;
        \item[TFS]: Turbolenza in FS;
        \item[FS]: Flussi Stratificati;
    }
    \end{description}
};
\node[scale=\sca,above right] at (-3, -1.2) {\textbf{Fig. 1} \hspace{0.1cm} TKE};

\end{tikzpicture}

%\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Two obvious things: adding `scale=\sca,` does not have any effect given that `\sca` is 1, and instead of hardcoding the figure number use the `caption` package.

Comment: @marmot when I vary, the general `scale`, `\sca` and `\scaa`, varies the whole figure correctly. I have already performed several tests. the code can be improved, but I am not very familiar with the package. As for the package `caption`, I know, this is just a test and an exercise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an attempt to simplify some things. I got rid of all the `rotate around`s in favor of polar coordinates and the `sloped` key, empty nodes, several explicit coordinates and so on. If you want to scale all nodes by a factor, you can add simply `every node/.append style={scale=\sca}` to the options of the tikzpicture. Also use `\gg` instead of `>>` and so on. This is by no means a fully optimized code but perhaps a step in this direction.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,portrate]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[margin=0.3in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\makeatletter
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xpt}{\@xpt}{5}{4}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xipt}{\@xipt}{6}{5}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xiipt}{\@xiipt}{6}{5}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xivpt}{\@xivpt}{\@xpt}{6}
\makeatother
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=bf}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=0.5,
node font=\small,
dashed axis/.style={dash pattern=on 4pt off 2pt},
moon line/.style={dash pattern=on 8pt off 4pt},
information text/.style={rounded corners, fill=Info Color, inner sep=1ex},
prg/.style={draw,fill=white}
]

\definecolor{Earth Color}{HTML}{358af3};
\definecolor{Sun Color}{HTML}{fffc00};
\definecolor{Moon Color}{HTML}{ddbd4c};
\definecolor{Info Color}{HTML}{eeeeee};

\def\ax{0}; %Posizione centrale assi%
\def\ay{0}
%%--Scale Factor --------------------
\def\sca{1}
\def\scaa{0.9}
% Asse x e y
\draw[{Stealth[length=0.01cm]}-{Stealth[length=0.2cm]}] (-16, 0) -- (16, 0) 
node [right=0.1em] {$P_{G}$} 
node[pos=2/32,above=0.8cm]{FS}
node[pos=1/4,above=3.8cm]{$P_{M}>0,P_{G}<0$}
node[pos=1/4,above]{$P_{M}\approx 0,P_{G}<0$}
node[pos=24.4/32,above]{$P_{G}\gg P_{M}$}
node[pos=30/32,above=0.8cm]{CL}
{[nodes=prg]  node[pos=0.1]{$R_{i}=+\infty$}
node[pos=0.9]{$R_{i}=+\infty$}}; % Asse 
\draw[{Stealth[length=0.001cm]}-{Stealth[length=0.2cm]}] (0, -0) -- (0, 16) 
node [above=0.1em] {$P_{M}$}
{[nodes=prg] node[pos=14/16]{CF} node[pos=12/16]{$P_{M}\gg P_{G}$}
node[pos=10/16] {$R_{i}=0$}};

%%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\path (2.5, 3)node [anchor=north west] {$P_{M}\approx P_{G}$}
(-4.5, 4) node [anchor=south east] {TFS};
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%
\draw[{Stealth[length=0.01cm]}-{Stealth[length=0.01cm]}] (0, -0) -- (15:15) 
node[prg,midway,sloped]{ $ R_{i}\approx-1$};

\draw[-] (0, -0) -- (165:15) node[prg,midway,sloped] {$R_{i}\approx+1$};

\draw[moon line] (110:15) -- (0, 0) -- (70:15);


\foreach \i in {5,...,1}
{
    \node at ({(160/3.8)*(\i)-396}:5cm) {\i};
};

%draw information box
\draw[shift={(6, 10)}] node[scale=\scaa,above right, text width=4cm,information text] {
    \small
    {\boldmath
        \textbf{\underline{Indice}} }
    \vspace{1ex}
    \small
    \begin{description}
        \item[CL]: Libera;
        \item[CM]: Mista;
        \item[CF]: Forzata;
        \item[TFS]: Turbolenza in FS;
        \item[FS]: Flussi Stratificati;
    \end{description}
};
\node[anchor=north,align=center,text width=4cm] at (0,-0.2) {\captionof{figure}{TKE.}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very well, thank you. there is always something to learn. I imagine we can find other solutions. I have inserted the line `[scale = 0.5,
every node/.append style={scale=1},.......`  to the options. in this way I get both the graph scale and the text scale.